# Latest version of Xcode stuck on installation (12.5)

Tags: xcode

I just updated my mac to macOS Big Sur, and am trying to update to the next version of XCode. It has been on 75-80% progress for hours:
[image]

Also, when I go to launchpad I see this:

[image]

Is anyone else having this issue or know how to fix it?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/services-account/download?path=/Developer_Tools/Xcode_13.2.1/Xcode_13.2.1.xip

will trigger a download

Comment: Common problem is lack of disk space. Check there are sufficient GB available for download and install.

Comment: The problem seems to be ongoing with macOS 12.4 (App Store Version 3.0 (1006.5.18.1.3)), and updating to Xcode 13.4.1.  System monitoring shows a extraordinary amount of disk I/O occurring with very very very unacceptably slow progress.

Comment: Given the long download time, I might guess that the App Store's cached account password (or session token) expires somewhere during this activity then starts choking hours into it. Suggest verifying a new login before starting the download. Also, turn off screensaver/sleep activities at the system level before starting.

Answer (score 1048, accepted):

As a first test to check if everything is just going fine but really slow, try this:

- Keep the App Store window open (thanks to @Dhruv Saraswat to point this out).
- Open the "Console" app (not the "Terminal", but the "Console")
- Go to the "Search bar" and type "App Store".
- Push "Start" button.
- Log lines will be added from time to time showing you how the installation process goes. In my case, I saw "... Completed: 825 of 1000", and some time later I got "... Completed: 826 to 1000", and so on.

That way you can at least check if everything is working, although really slow. You can then guess how long it will take to the "Completed: 1000 to 1000" step in your own situation.

Comment: This was very helpful to see the actual progress behind the scene. Really appreciate your solution :)

Comment: oh my God. You are so right. it works. it really has a little progress, at least I can notice it. thanks. but why is this slow and looks like stuck. I mean even the pause/stop button for the installation doesn't work. I try to pause the installation in app store, and nothing happens.

Comment: I followed the instructions and it went all the way up to 958 out of 1000 and finally failed with error "The update was canceled because the application integrity could not be verified." It started again at 0. This has happened at least 3 times. :(

Comment: I think this answer offers an alternative approach that doesn't require downloading a version that's not on the app store, so I'm check-marking it.

Comment: There are more chances to finally failed and it takes more time. So instead of downloading from App Store, is it not a good option to download dmg and install it.

Comment: With an update from Xcode v13 to Xcode v13.1 on a MacBook Air 2020 i7 16GB RAM, 270 GB free SSD the progress is like this: at **16:24:51**: Fraction completed: **0.8970** at **16:50:33**: Fraction completed: **0.9150** at **17:49:51**: Fraction completed: **0.9680**

Comment: in the console I had to hide the left pane (sources) in order to see the whole lines. I could not scroll in the log pane.

Comment: this should be first step for all of us that are so impatient. this allowed me to be patient while the counter, sometimes very slowly increasing, still moved -- and it finished cleanly without me mucking around.

Comment: Nice job. I actually could see it was stuck on line 811 and then turned off the Antivirus and voila continued the installation process.

Comment: I didn't see anything in the console. What I did was kill the installd process which allowed me to restart the install from app store. I can now see the `x of 1000` counters in my console. `sudo kill -9 $(pgrep -x system_installd)`

Comment: @EricUldall This seemed to work for me too. I just did ```ps aux | grep appstore``` to find ```appstoreagent``` then as you suggested ```sudo kill <PID>```. When I clicked back on the app store I was able to start the process again and see the progress in the console. Lets see if it finishes.

Comment: @Chris Mine never finished the subsequent time. I ended up killing it, uninstalling, then getting the .xip file. That worked :D

Comment: @EricUldall guess I was lucky. It worked for me. So thanks for your tip (even if it didn't work for you)

Comment: I needed to keep the `App Store` window open for this to work. Thanks for this excellent answer.

Comment: really helpful answer, I was about to restart my Mac to get rid of this wait, luckily checked your answer before that

Comment: My process was stuck on 999 of 1000 for a looong time. But as soon as I opened the App Store Window in parallel to console, it finished the install. Probably magical thinking, but anyway…

Comment: And the new stupid problem was just that in my localized macOS there is no "console" at all because it was brilliantly named "Systemmeddelanden" (literally meaning System messages). So it's very amusing how much the world's richest company can break their own work when some real programmer just `apt install gcc` and everything works. Amazing that the company only has 1000 trillion dollars and still cannot release their own installer for their own app for their own machine. Reminds me why I chose Linux to get some work done. I've just been trying for 3 days to install an app

Comment: Apple has abstracted the user experience so much that I now long for the day that I can ditch my Apple computers and go back to Windows where progress bars actually mean something.

Comment: Great, but why is it so slow? I thought the App Store would be the fastest, easiest, way to get XCode installed, of all things.

Comment: Omg thank you! I was almost about to cancel the installation after one and half hour thinking it is stuck. But then I opened the console and just saw 999/1000, 1000/1000 and the installation was complete! :-D

Comment: Worked for me! Oh, my roadmap  `Fraction completed: 0.8610 / Completed: 861 of 1000`! Oh, man.

Comment: I dont get it, push start button just logs me out shrug

Comment: @CoryC, did you keep the App Store window open?

Comment: Yeh i did idk why it did that.. (i ended up nuking it to removing it altogether)

Comment: Instead of keeping App Store open for this to work I just searched for `appstore` instead of `App Store`. The process is going to take about 2 weeks to finish on my MacBook Air I7. This is really frustrating and the official Apple channels are all very quiet about this issue.

Comment: @JohnK.N., have u tried a faster Internet connection? Maybe that 2-week-period is not only determined by your computer, that is something u cannot change, but also by your Internet connection, that is something u can easily try to change temporarily (somewhere else, or using your 4/5G mobile phone as a wifi router).

Comment: @thelawnmowerman It downloaded in 30 minutes and was installing for a solid 6 hours in the end. I just had to plug in the MacBook and make sure it didn't go into any form of power saving / hybernation mode. Then Xcode was eventually "installed".

Comment: Everything is so hard on Mac. I dont understand why people like those devices. So basics on Windows PCs, you need to google to find out a command for it. A simple progress bar apple cannot even show.

Comment: Don't install Xcode from the AppStore. Get it from the Developer portal and install it from there instead. It's not stuck on updating. The UI doesn't do a good job of informing the user as to the progress of the installation: https://dirkstrauss.com/xcode-stuck-updating-m1-macbook-pro

Comment: Thank you so much! For anyone else who finds this, it's totally normal for the same message to repeat for several minutes as it works.

I'll definitely download it manually next time, but for now this helped me learn about a great tool for searching logs.

Comment: Thanks, It was really helpful I was downloading it again and again but after reading this Answer I understood and waited till the 1000 /1000 completed in the console. Finally its done.

Comment: Am I the only one, where it stops at 981/1000 and then restarts at 0/1000?

Comment: This answer is deeply reassuring. It shows that when the progress wheel becomes fickle and detached from reality, the daemon under the hood is dedicated and persisting.

Comment: It does not show anything on `App store`

Comment: Thanks a lot, this is a very useful answer. And always make sure you don't have any firewall blocks in your Mac. And also try to different networks.

Answer (score 35):

This is weird behaviour everyone face nowadays when installing from AppStore. Instead of that download dmg of required xcode version from apple developer account and install.

Please refer below link to download XCode versions.

[Xcode download link for all versions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Above link contains download link from XCode version 1.0 till the latest.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little on the process to download and install manually?

Comment: @AndyP edited answer. In this provide link to download xcode all versions.

Comment: I had the same situation. Downloaded latest from dev account and worked perfect. Appstore download was stuck for hours . Enough disk space(100GB) was also available.

Comment: This should be the only answer. Search for the xcode version you need: https://developer.apple.com/download/all/

Answer (score 33):

mine was stuck for about 3 days and even rebooting didn't help!
i was trying to update to xcode 13.2.1 on MacOS Monterey
what i did was:

1- opened Activity Monitor and force quitted "installd" (not sure if it was necessary though!)

2- opened Launcher, held Option key (to make the icons jiggle) and clicked the x on xcode's corner! asked me if i want to delete the app and i confirmed but magically it stayed and when i opened it it was updated to the latest version! so basically it was done installing just didn't know it.

Comment: applied step 2 and it worked

Comment: Ha - interestingly applied only Step 1 and it worked - Version 13.4 (13F17a).

Comment: applied step 1, and the installation started over from re-downloading, it is a good result, better than being stuck. (btw., it is xcode 14.2 in my case)

Comment: This was the solution!!  Thank you for posting what worked for you.

Answer (score 23):

I was stuck at Completed : 808 of 1000.

This is workaround.

Left down side of App store application screen, there is an account button.

Press account, then you can see message you should ACCEPT something.

Press accept and enter iCloud password.

Then magic. Console's app store log numbers going up.

Comment: When I tried this, there was nothing I needed to accept, but I did need to log in to my Apple account, and that fixed it.

Comment: Mine was completing very slowly, so I tried this, which did seem to accelerate the completion rate, but after it hit 1000, the App Store just went back to showing that the app has an update.

Comment: This trick worked for me when I tried to update XCode and it was stuck in forever loop.

Comment: Life saver. No way I would have figured this out. Thank you!

Answer (score 21):

in my case force quit installd, close and open appstore, run update again

Comment: Looks like installd gets stuck. I monitored progress for a while, then killed installd, then re-opened app store and it started downloading again.  This time the download was a LOT faster until it got to about 0.800 then it slowed down again.  The logs showed connection re-tries and TLS re-negotiation.

Answer (score 19):

Had the same issue after updating my MacBook to Big Sur and trying to update Xcode to version 12.5.
Tried to reinstall, reboot my Mac, delete the app and install it again from App Store.

Decided to **leave the installation overnight** and it helped! In the morning Xcode was installed successfully.

Comment: this is the perfect and most correct and legit answer. It 100% worked without any hacks.

Answer (score 14):

Best way is to open 'console'  (not terminal) app on Mac and type 'App Store' in the search bar then hit 'go' button as per first screen shot

[image]

You will start to see the lines come in and you need to make it wide enough so you get to see the parts number and notice the progress like in the second screenshot

[image]

You will notice some of those numbers will move fast, some will take up to 10 minutes, but at least you know you are not 'stuck'!

Answer (score 11):

Just FYI: On the latest Macbook Air M1, 8GB RAM, 256GB SSD, I installed XCode from the App Store. I had exactly the same issue. I thought my installation is stuck. I left Macbook for the whole night, then it downloaded XCode (around 12 GB). After that, it started installing it. I left it for the whole day and didn't touch it. In the evening XCode was installed. I just needed to leave it for around 24 hours to do the job.

Comment: same happened with me

Comment: same situation. don't get nervous

Answer (score 9):

I had exactly the same situation, I updated MacOS and then updated Xcode to 12.5.1 and it got stuck on 7.2GB of 7.2GB. I left it for 4 hours with nothing happening (but in Activity Monitor 'installd' was working away). I left it overnight and it had sorted itself out by the morning.

Comment: I left it overnight, and still stuck. It's killing me

Answer (score 8):

If (like me) you only need the command-line tools, you may want to give this a try:

1. force-quit installd (using ActivityMonitor or ps -kill)
2. run `xcode-select --install` from the Terminal command line

Worked for me!

Comment: Force quit installd and any instances of installer currently running in ActivityMonitor allowed me to break the logjam and install/update a backlog of apps that were stuck for days.

Answer (score 5):

Although it does not speed up, but in Mac App Store, you should see the spinning wheel next in Xcode - place the cursor ON the wheel and you should see the installation progress (eg 52%).

If it does not move, cancel the Xcode installation and start again.

Answer (score 5):

For me, the solution suggested by @thelawnmowerman worked perfectly.

Just need to check the number that is currently in progress out of the total threads. Once it completes the total, in a few mins, the xcode can be launched.
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Confirm it has in 13.2 and 13.2.1 as well. Viewing the console app in the top answer will show you when it's done

Comment: Yes upgrading to 13.2.1 caused me this same hung install issue ( on Monterey 12.1), left mine at 805 out of 1000 for 24hrs and it never progressed.  I suspect that the App Store software really isn't great at handling large downloads and installs so I'll be sure to always download the update and install manually from now on.

Answer (score 2):

I updated Xcode on M1 macbook pro with lots of RAM and lots of SSD MacOS 12.1 today from 12.2 to 12.3. It took 4.5 hours. So patience helps, and watching the logs as well.

Comment: in my case `ASDAppQuery.resultsDidChange 497799835: <NSProgress: 0x600003cd4d20> : Parent: 0x0 (portion: 0) / Fraction completed: 0.8050 / Completed: 805 of 1000`

Logs are looking like this

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue. I monitored the process using @**thelawnmowerman** answer. But the process was getting stuck after progressing.

I terminated the App Store every time the process got stuck and opening it again also started monitoring process again, it started progressing every time and I reached to the 1000 (100%).

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem, and for me, the tips in this thread did not work. What I found to be the problem is that App Store didn't think I had enough space when in fact I had enough space for Xcode.

To solve the "space" problem you can create a dummy file and directly remove it. This allows you to trick your computer that you actually have enough space. (Has to do with containers, read here for more info: https://medium.com/geekculture/installing-xcode-with-not-enough-disk-space-available-b96c8f17115b)

STEP BY STEP GUIDE:

1. Open the Terminal
2. Move to the location where you want to create your file using cd. Like `cd Documents`
3. Now use command mkfile G your-file-name.ext ( example: `mkfile 4G mymovie.mov` => will create a movie file with name mymovie of size 4GB)
   Hit Enter, It will take some time to complete the process (depends on the file size)
4. When the command completes the prompt should return and a file would be created.
5. Go to finder and remove your file. (Move to trash)
6. Emeditly install Xcode again.

Hope you find it helpful :)

Answer (score 1):

I am using a base Macbook Air M1 2021 (8 GB RAM). I downloaded Xcode from the
[apple developer portal](https://developer.apple.com/download/applications/) and installed it with the `xip` command. Open your Terminal and type the below:

```
xip -x ~/file-location
```

Double-clicking the file takes too long, the above command took ~5-8 minutes to expand the file. After that just move it to the applications folder so you can find it in the Launchpad.

Reference to answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56913909/15425440

Answer (score 1):

Solved - My new MacBook Air M2 was struggling with downloading and installing Xcode.  The problem, I think, was that the laptop sleeps after a short period of time and that stops the download/install process.  Download/install restarts at 80% or 0% when the laptop is reawakened - repeat.  A simple way to avoid the laptop from sleeping is to open the Terminal application (Application/Utilities/Terminal) and type "caffeinate".  That prevents the laptop from sleeping and lets the download/install process complete itself.  When done type control-c into the Terminal and it will quit caffeinate.

Answer (score 0):

Turning off the file shield of your antivirus will helped in my case.

While an anti-virus shouldn’t technically block an app from the Mac App Store, it seems that Xcode is an app with its own unique set of problems which is why disabling the anti-virus works in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

The Console is very helpful.  It shows that installation is working, albeit slowly.

I had to download xCode 3 times.  Re-install it 3 times.  All in all about 8-12 hours effort.

It is still proceeding, SLOWLY.

It would be very helpful if the Apple team put in a better "installation progress" indicator -- like exists for so many other products.

Answer (score 0):

I faced a similar issue while installing the 13.3 version. My progress bar was showing installing for about 1-2 hours and then it started showing waiting. What eventually worked for me was installing it using terminal code "xcode-select --install".

Answer (score 0):

This was so frustrating for me
When I checked the console, I felt like there was a problem with my account.
Because I changed my password once before.

So I went to App Store -> my account -> I had to login again.

Answer (score 0):

After trying to update to Xcode 14.1 on Ventura for nearly 24 hours, I eventually trashed the Xcode application, rebooted, started only the App Store, and did a new install, leaving the App Store in the foreground. It downloaded (about 7 GB in 20 minutes) and completed the install in less than an hour on my M1 Mac mini.

Background:

After updating to Ventura, there was an update to Xcode 14.1 in the App Store. As with previous versions, I had trouble installing it. This time though, the install would progress to 61% (seen by hovering the mouse over the spinning circle in App Store), then stay there. Filtering for `ASDAppQuery` in the Console, as suggested in other answers, showed progress for a while, but then also stopped. The installd process was still using a lot of CPU. However, after a while it would stop doing so. It seemed that the App Store app would stop, and a couple of times I checked Activity Monitor and saw that it was in "App Nap" mode. After waking up again, the appstoreagent would run at 95% CPU (one core) for a while, followed by installd running again, at around 300% CPU. This cycle continued, but with no progress. I tried leaving it overnight, but in the morning it was in the same state: neither appstoreagent nor installd doing anything, but then seeming to wake up and grind away again, but making no progress. I had also tried quitting the App Store and starting again, but the same kept happening - going to 61%, then spinning away with no progress indication. Finally, I decided to trash Xcode, reboot, and install - that worked quickly and flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

fixed forcing close the installd process and run again the App store

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who's still stuck try this

-Quit App Store 
-Paste this in terminal

```bash
sudo killall appstoreagent
sudo killall com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StoreAService
sudo killall com.apple.AppStoreDaemon.StorePrivilegedTaskService
sudo killall installd
sudo killall installcoordinationd
sudo killall system_installd
sudo killall uninstalld
```

Launch App Store, it should start making progress now verify this by launching console and filtering for "appstore"
[image: console app showing log for appstore]

Answer (score 0):

Same happened to me when upgrading to XCode 14.3.1 from previous version. The installer got stuck at 5.7 GB of 5.7 GB even after several reboots. Then getting hint from this answer [above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70563990/1742325), I opened Applications folder in the Finder and force-deleted the XCode app and this forced redownload of XCode and  this time it installed correctly. Albeit it took some time stuck at installation too but not too long.

Answer (score 0):

**This worked for me!**

Download another app.

> The Installd process was not running when I opened activity monitor  this seemed to start it and install Xcode properly

Answer (score 0):

Turn off 1.1.1.1, App Store will start (resume) download/update Xcode.
[image]

Answer (score -17):

You can open the app store, search XCode and click the stop button. Worked!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I'm glad this worked for you, but it did not work for me; no amount of clicking on the stop button had any effect on a hanging install of Xcode. The App Store did not return to a usable state until I deleted the partially-downloaded Xcode, logged out, and logged in again.

Comment: Yes, but your answer doesn't address the question itself. Why is xcode taking so long to install and how to fix it.

Comment: E. Bishop, I would appreciate if you could have mentioned where did you delete the partially downloaded xcode from and what exactly you logged out and in...