# Xcode 9 only for members of the Apple Developer Program

Tags: download, xcode9-beta, xcode9

Did they change it so you need to be in the Apple Developer Program to access the latest Xcode beta version or GM Seed? Because I remember downloading Xcode Beta not too long ago. It says on https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/WhatsNewXcode/xcode_9/xcode_9.html :

Prerelease versions of Xcode are made available from developer.apple.com to authorized seed developers, packaged in a compressed XIP file.

Does seed developer equals being a member in the Apple Developer Program?

Comment: For some reason, Xcode 9 beta and Xcode 8.3.3 are not yet listed under https://developer.apple.com/download/more/

Comment: @Cœur yes it's working thank you.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/1033581

Comment: This may help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44390162/download-install-xcode-9-beta-version-without-premium-developer-account/44390183#44390183

Answer (score 1):

You may need a developer account to access the betas. However, you will not need a paid account. It is fairly easy and free to create a developer account and download the betas.

### Creating a Developer Account

Create an AppleID normally at:

https://appleid.apple.com/account#!&page=create

*Alternatively, if you already have an AppleID that you would like to create a developer account with, you can use that.*

Go to http://developer.apple.com/account.

Log in with your AppleID. Follow the steps provided to create your Developer Account.

### Downloading Betas

After you have created a developer account, you can download the betas from https://developer.apple.com/download/.

Make sure that you do not go to https://beta.apple.com. This is the public beta program and is coming in July, it also doesn't have the Xcode beta.