# How to update XCode installed from XIP file?

Tags: xcode, macos, macos-sierra, macos-high-sierra

I have installed XCode 9 from XIP file and then moved it to Applications folder and it even shows up in Launchpad. I have the latest version of Sierra with security update also installed but app store doesn't seem to accept that I have it installed (Xcode) and instead of providing up with with the update it's asking me to install XCode 9.1. Is there any solution or I have to download and install the XCode 9.1 version?
There might be a way around to add some var to the path so the app store could detect it as installation form itself and update it right away!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's no way found yet. Keep downloading the new version from the Apple developer portal or refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/3077444). Or Delete the one you installed from xip and download and install it from the App Store.