# How to install Xcode in MAX OSX running in VMware - Xcode can’t be installed on because OS X version 10.12 or later is required

Tags: ios, xcode, macos, ubuntu-16.04, vmware

I want to get started with iOS app development and I could not afford a MAC computer at this time, so I installed MAC OS X Sierra in a Virtual Machine in VMware by following [this video tutorial](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0ahUKEwiC2ueGlJHZAhUClCwKHQ2jD6kQtwIIJTAA&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3D7QAsYobLJtE&usg=AOvVaw1lJWmFNM7tYO1hy1c17GD6).

The next step is getting XCode. So I opened App Store and searched for it, and i am finding an error which says that `MAC OS X 10.12.6 is required.` I have searched this error on the web, and I found solutions like updating the OS etc. but nothing is found in the `Updates` tab of App Store yet.

So I was thinking if something like downloading and installing a previous version of XCode is possible and probably it will solve my problem.

In that case:

1. Which version of Xcode will be compatible with my OS?
2. How to download and install? Today was the first time I got my hands on a (kind of a) MAC OS.

Please guide.

[image]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/468724

Comment: I would recommend you to upgrade to High Sierra which supports Xcode 9

Answer (score 3):

I guess you are trying to install the latest version of Xcode which is incompatible with the macOS which you had install currently. So to resolved this issue you are required to update the latest macOS or installing the previous versioned Xcode. You can find the previous version Xcode(i.e, 9.0 or lesser) tools from [**here**](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/).

***Note:*** you must have created or owned a personal apple developers account in order to download it

Comment: I think actually you need 8.3.3 for it to br compatible with 10.12