# How can I use SwiftUI on Windows to make an iOS app?

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, windows, swiftui

So I have experience with programming already (Java, JS, Python), but I’m a complete newbie with Swift. I have a computer that runs Windows, but I would like to use SwiftUI and assume that I can’t without having macOS. I’ve heard of using Hackintosh to get around this OS problem, but is there anything else I could do? Thanks to whoever can help me with this.

Comment: While you can't use SwiftUI on Windows, there many other ways to create iOS apps.

Comment: Regardless of the language or framework you use, you ultimately need macOS running somewhere as the tools to build an iOS app are only on macOS.

Answer (score 3):

Native way to create native iOS apps is done using XCode.app, which can only be run on MacOS.

Hackintosh is a solution to run MacOS on unsupported hardware. It is possible, but be prepared for many nights spent setting it up, unless you have perfectly compatible hardware.

Another way to consider is to run it in a virtual machine, see [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48641895/how-to-install-xcode-in-max-osx-running-in-vmware-xcode-can-t-be-installed-on).

BEST solution: Considering that apple developer accounts is about $100 a year, it is not a huge overpay to buy a used MacMini for your development (if money is an issue).

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you could get some experience without a Mac if you set up Ubuntu in a VM and used
https://github.com/TokamakUI/Tokamak

From the link above:

> About:
> SwiftUI-compatible framework for building browser apps with WebAssembly and native apps for other platforms

> Requirements
> ...
>
> - Swift 5.6 or later and Ubuntu 18.04/20.04 if you'd like to use Linux. Other Linux distributions are currently not supported.

Answer (score 0):

There are no ways (other than renting a cloud mac) to develop IOS/MacOS/Apple Watch project using non-MacOS operating system. You either buy one, rent one, or built a hackintosh