# Upload IPA with Xcode7.3 with iOS 9.3 SDK issue

Tags: ios, upload, app-store, ipa

The project is made in Xcode 7.3 with Swift 2.3.
Getting the following issue while uploading build on AppStore.

> error itms-90725: "sdk version issue. this app was built with the ios '9.3' sdk. all new ios apps submitted to the app store must be built with the ios '11.0' sdk or later, included in xcode [9.0] or later. please update xcode and rebuild your app."

How to resolve this issue, can anyone suggest.

Comment: update your xcode version.

Comment: The error is quite clear about what you need to do. You can't use old, outdated tools. Apple likes you to stay current.

Comment: Yes, that's true. Now onwards we need to build our project with updated one. Also need to focus on iPhone-X display. Now Apple made it compulsory for all developers for new apps as well as app updates. So you need to Update your Xcode.

Answer (score 0):

> > **error itms-90725: "sdk version issue. this app was built with the ios '9.3' sdk. all new ios apps submitted to the app store must be built with the ios '11.0' sdk or later, included in xcode [9.0] or later. please update xcode and rebuild your app."
> >     **

Apple doesn't accept the ipa build with less than iOS 11.0 and Xcode 9.0. The app submitted to App Store should be of 64-bit and build with iOS 11 sdk and Xcode 9.0 or later.

So now its time to update your Xcode and app.:)

**From Apple**

> Starting April 2018, all new iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK, included in Xcode 9 or later. All new apps for iPhone, including universal apps, must support the Super Retina display of iPhone X.

For more information visit [this](https://developer.apple.com/ios/submit/)

Comment: Is there any alternative solution?

Comment: nopes no other solution you must download the latest Xcode.

Comment: Ultimately you will submit your app to App Store and apple won't allow it.

Comment: Apple has updated the document. They changed April 2018 to July 2018. But still not accepting the app. Seems the only way is to update the xcode.

Answer (score 0):

Well for `Xcode 7.3` the maximum of `iOS` `version` Supported is `9.x.x`, your app submitted with 7.3 don't have latest iOS version selected that is 11.3

and currently, we are having iOS 11.3.* for that, we need the latest `Xcode 9.3`

download the `latest Xcode` and try to build/submit the app again.

[Xcode download link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution! I tried 2-3 days and now it works! You can use older versions of xcode with iOS 11.0 or 12.0 sdk. It's not that short please follow the steps carefully.

1-)Install xcode 9 or xcode 10 into your mac (or another mac if you have)

2-)GO >> Applications >> right click x code 9/10 and show package content. Contents >> Developer >> Platforms >> iPhoneOS Platform >> Developer >> SDKs >> iPhoneOS11 or 12 SDK. COPY SDKsettings.plist file into another folder on desktop. Please open a folder on desktop and paste into that folder. Don't paste it on desktop directly.

3-)Now for the older version GO >> Applications >> ... >> SDKs >> iPhoneOS9.2 SDK in the older xcode such as 7-8 version. Click on the SDKsettings.plist and send it into trash folder. Open another folder on desktop and move it on that folder from trash. No copy-paste here.

4-)NOW open the folder which contains newest SDK file (mentioned in the 2nd step). Copy that file and paste into the older x code >> GO >> APP >> ... SDKs >> into BOTH iphoneOS9.2sdk and iphoneOS.sdk folders. Change the folder name from iphoneOS9.2 to 11.0 or 12.0 depending the newest SDK you have. Don't change the name of iphoneOS folder.

5-)Open your older xcode and now you can see the SDK version is changed to 11 or 12 in build settings (target).

6-)Still not enough --- More to do.

7-)Open a new single view app project in the newest xcode. No need to code. You just need the newest ASSESTS.car file. COPY your assets folder from your original project (x code 7/8) to this new project (x code 9/10). Make sure that you fill all AppIcons on the assests in the newest version of xcode. In the info part please add the security things you use in your original code (such as ATC, NSLocation etc.) Also add a row and write CFBundleIconName >> AppIcon. Build and RUN the project. Open the archieve from organizer. Right click and show in finder. Then right click show package contents. Products >> Applications >> Right click and show package contents. Copy ONLY THAT files >> all.png files + Assets.car + Info.plist + PkgInfo and paste into another new folder on desktop.

8-) Now open your original code in xcode 7/8 etc. Build and RUN the code. Open the archieve from organizer. Right click and show in finder. Double click Info.plist file. Add a row and write CFBundleIconName >> AppIcon.
Now turn back and Products >> Applications >> Right click and show package contents.

9-)Copy all files on the desktop folder mentioned in the 7th step. Paste the files into folder in the 8th step. Click replace.

10-)Now upload your archieve from xcode 7/8 to appstore!
DONE..

Comment: If you build the app with VS/Xamarin you only need steps 1 to 6. At least I was able to upload the app to appstore and submit it to review. I run a VM (vmware) with El Capitan where XCode 9 and 10 does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurs based on two parts. I work on Xcode8.3
Here is what I did

1. OS SDK which can be fixed by replacing a required SKD(OS11 SDK)in Iphones10.2 folder. You can paste only SKDsetting.plist
2. AppIcon issue since Xcode 9 requires AppIcon1024x1024 in App file. In my case, I used the same Assets file and put the different AppIcon between Xcode8 and 9 as an unassigned image. Then insert "CFBundleIconName" as a string type and AppIcon on info.plist 
   **PS**. you can config plist file directly on Xcode.

After all, validate the app and upload to Apple. Wait for launching the App to the World.

It works like a charm!
Hope this help.