# Minimum hardware and software requirements to install Xcode 10.0

Tags: xcode, xcode10

What are the minimum hardware and software specifications to install Xcode 10.0 in a MAC mini and Macbook Pro? How much RAM is required? What processor is required?

Comment: Read the release notes. Of course Apple provides details. In fact release notes start of with that specific information.

Comment: For an unofficial answer, you may easily spot minimal OS versions required at https://xcodereleases.com/ and maximal OS versions supported at [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/1033581)

Comment: @Cœur, thanks for reply and providing a good link. Please upvote my question. Sure, I will not change a question.

Comment: @MilanRathod Sorry, I do not plan to vote on your question: I believe that question has ephemeral value (so should be downvoted), yet, you already collected your share of downvotes here (-11 votes, +8 votes), so I'll leave it as is. If you're interested in Apple products, this kind of questions may better fit on https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: The accepted meta answer from [Stack Exchange and hardware questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/270703/stack-exchange-and-hardware-questions) also points out to use apple.stackexchange.com for your question.

Comment: @Desdenova The release notes do not include system requirements. It references only the OS version, which requires the previous minor OS version. You can work your way back through multiple release notes but eventually hit a wall of no longer available info. This is not useful, and nobody here can help as Apple does not list the requirements anywhere. It is a very valid question, perhaps in the wrong forum. It could help finding a suitable development system, especially a used one. But only Apple can give a realiable answer, and that, sadly, does not exist.

Comment: For anyone still looking for this kind of info, I found a fairly recent article at https://www.macworld.co.uk/feature/mac/best-mac-development-3449754/. You can skip the irrelevant part about display sizes (you'll need an external display for day-to-day work anyway unless you have Eagle's eyes). The article covers the most important hardware specs and gives recommendations. It neglects mentioning the emulator, which is a very resource-hungry component. But with the 16GB RAM recommended by the article you shound be OK for a while, even running more than one instance of the emulator.

Comment: At the time of writing, a recent Macbook Air or a Mini with 16GB RAM are the most suitable and future-proof options unless you are on an unlimited budget. I'm running Xcode on a 2012 Mac Mini with a quad core i7 and 16GB RAM but is sense its end as a development machine is near.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

These are specification for Xcode 10

1. Xcode 10 requires a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 or later..
2. Xcode 10 includes SDKs for iOS 12, watchOS 5, macOS 10.14, and tvOS 12.
3. Xcode 10 supports running multiple concurrent versions of the Xcode app and of any associated tools such as Simulator.
4. Xcode 10 can coexist with previous versions of Xcode.

reference: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_release_notes