# Xcode 10b5 - duplicate symbol linker error, can't compile with Crashlytics

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, google-fabric, xcode10

I'm trying to compile my project, which has both Firebase, Crashlytics/Fabric, and a bunch of other stuff, with Xcode 10 beta 5.
It fails during linking with these errors:

```
Ld /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname normal arm64 (in target: appname)
        cd /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname
        export IPHONEOS_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=9.0
        /Users/Username/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/bin/clang -arch arm64 -isysroot /Users/Username/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS12.0.sdk -L/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AFNetworking -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Actions -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/AppAuth -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bluepeer -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Bolts -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CocoaAsyncSocket -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/CocoaLumberjack -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Color-Picker-for-iOS -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DNPWPSPrinter -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/DataCompression -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/EOSFTPServer -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKCoreKit -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FBSDKLoginKit -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FastttCamera -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseAuth -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseCore -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseDatabase -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/FirebaseStorage -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMAppAuth -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GTMSessionFetcher -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Gloss -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoldRaccoon -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/GoogleToolboxForMac -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/HHServices -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/JPSVolumeButtonHandler -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/M13BadgeView -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/ObjectiveDropboxOfficial -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/PhoneNumberKit -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/Protobuf -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/TPCircularBuffer -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/leveldb-library -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/nanopb -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/upnpx -F/Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/xaphodObjCUtils -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Fabric/iOS -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/FirebaseABTesting/Frameworks -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/FirebaseAnalytics/Frameworks -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/FirebaseDynamicLinks/Frameworks -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/FirebaseInstanceID/Frameworks -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/FirebaseRemoteConfig/Frameworks -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/TwitterCore/iOS -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/TwitterKit/iOS -F/Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/cascablecore-binaries/Binaries/iOS -filelist /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appname.LinkFileList -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @loader_path/Frameworks -Xlinker -rpath -Xlinker @executable_path/Frameworks -miphoneos-version-min=9.0 -dead_strip -Xlinker -object_path_lto -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appname_lto.o -Xlinker -export_dynamic -Xlinker -no_deduplicate -fobjc-arc -fobjc-link-runtime -L/Users/Username/Downloads/Xcode-beta.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/swift/iphoneos -Xlinker -add_ast_path -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appname.swiftmodule -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -framework AFNetworking -framework AVFoundation -framework Accounts -framework Actions -framework AppAuth -framework AssetsLibrary -framework Bluepeer -framework Bolts -framework CFNetwork -framework CocoaAsyncSocket -framework CocoaLumberjack -framework Color_Picker_for_iOS -framework CoreData -framework CoreGraphics -framework CoreMedia -framework CoreText -framework Crashlytics -framework DNPWPSPrinter -framework DataCompression -framework EOSFTPServer -framework FBSDKCoreKit -framework FBSDKLoginKit -framework Fabric -framework FastttCamera -framework FirebaseABTesting -framework FirebaseAnalytics -framework FirebaseAuth -framework FirebaseCore -framework FirebaseCoreDiagnostics -framework FirebaseDatabase -framework FirebaseDynamicLinks -framework FirebaseInstanceID -framework FirebaseNanoPB -framework FirebaseRemoteConfig -framework FirebaseStorage -framework Foundation -framework GTMAppAuth -framework GTMSessionFetcher -framework Gloss -framework GoldRaccoon -framework GoogleToolboxForMac -framework HHServices -framework JPSVolumeButtonHandler -framework M13BadgeView -framework MessageUI -framework MobileCoreServices -framework ObjectiveDropboxOfficial -framework PhoneNumberKit -framework Protobuf -framework QuartzCore -framework SafariServices -framework Security -framework Social -framework StoreKit -framework SystemConfiguration -framework TPCircularBuffer -framework TwitterCore -framework TwitterKit -framework UIKit -framework leveldb -framework nanopb -framework upnpx -framework xaphodObjCUtils -weak_framework WebKit -ObjC -lc++ -licucore -lsqlite3 -lz -lctemplate-ios -letpan-ios -lxml2 -lsasl2 -liconv -ltidy -lz -lc++ -lresolv -stdlib=libc++ -ObjC /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMailCore-ios.a -framework SafariServices -framework CascableCore -framework Security -framework CFNetwork -framework MessageUI -framework StoreKit -framework GameKit -framework StopKit -framework Pods_appname -Xlinker -dependency_info -Xlinker /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Intermediates.noindex/appname.build/Debug-iphoneos/appname.build/Objects-normal/arm64/appname_dependency_info.dat -o /Users/Username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/appname-lastnamepjksdzfewpftlvqzuglaxplu/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/appname.app/appname

    duplicate symbol l086 in:
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSFileManager.o)
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSInternalReport.o)
    duplicate symbol l087 in:
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSFileManager.o)
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSInternalReport.o)
    duplicate symbol l088 in:
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSSettings.o)
        /Users/Username/iPhone-dev/appname/Pods/Crashlytics/iOS/Crashlytics.framework/Crashlytics(CLSInternalReport.o)
....<many more omitted>
```

What's the trick to get Google Fabric / Crashlytics working with Xcode 10?

**Edit:** Thanks to all who have commented so far. What i've tried so far:

- tried reinstalling the pods / clearing pod caches
- tried cleaning build folder, then restarting xcode
- tried playing with -ObjC linker flag. It does indeed look like this flag has something to do with the issue, but unfortunately I need this flag active as I use objective-c frameworks that have static categories on classes

Comment: Did the project work in previous versions of Xcode? Or is it just since 10b5 that it’s failing?

Comment: @Fogmeister Tried cleaning build folder, reinstalling pods after killing pod repo caches, restarting xcode. Worked fine on xcode 9. This is my first attempt to move this project to xcode 10.

Comment: i'm getting "ld: 163 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64"

Comment: same problem here, it is ok in 10b4, but error in 10b5

Comment: My project can build and run on simulator but fail on archiving.

Comment: I have the same problem with Xcode 10 beta5. It worked without issues on beta4. So far I can only say that there is a problem with using "-ObjC" or "-force_load" flags in linker. I can also confirm that it only fails to build for real devices and works without issues for Simulators. Apple will need to fix this.

Comment: I have the same issue but also on Xcode beta 4. Removing the `-ObjC` linker flag seems to help but then the app crashes on `+[CLSFileManager defaultCenter]: unrecognized selector sent to class`

Comment: Im having the same issues. Ive tried adding the $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/$(INFOPLIST_PATH) to the run script but that didn't work.

Comment: Tried all the suggestions above and none of them worked, I reverted back to xcode10b4 and problem solved..;)

Comment: Facing same issue with XCode 10 beta 5

Comment: Found Xcode 10b4 download link here for anyone who needs to revert: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file

Comment: You can find every Xcode versions (beta and release) here : https://xcodereleases.com/

Comment: The Crashlytics team is aware of the issue, see https://twitter.com/crashlytics/status/1024359450436685824

Comment: here is xcode 10 beta 4 download link https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_beta_4/Xcode_10_beta_4.xip

Comment: Got a response from Apple staff. See Eskimo's response here. https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/106694

Comment: @ACVM: Actually the download link (3 comments above) works fine still.

Comment: https://download.developer.apple.com/Developer_Tools/Xcode_10_beta_4/Xcode_10_beta_4.xip

Comment: Can anyone confirm this issue is solved with xc10b6?

Comment: Just downloaded the newest beta. Issue solved!

Comment: In Beta 6 is seems be fixed!

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Fixed for me with Xcode 10b6 (released this morning)!

Comment: [This answer is being discussed on meta.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373647/2263631)