# Duplicate symbol error when using Xcode 10 beta

Tags: xcode, flurry

I get the following duplicate symbol errors when attempting to build my project on an actual device using Xcode 10 beta 5:

[image]

The errors don't occur when building to the simulator nor do they occur when using previous versions of Xcode and I'm not attempting to include the library multiple times (This is an old project which doesn't use pods but it's always compiled fine in the past). I'd assume I'm using another library that also includes PLCrashReport but I can't understand why I wouldn't see the same error when building with older versions of Xcode.

Anyone having similar issues using Xcode 10?

Comment: Yes, it's the same as this problem: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602785/xcode-10b5-duplicate-symbol-linker-error-cant-compile-with-crashlytics ... stick to beta 4 for now. Apple will have to fix it.

Comment: Thank you for the response Sami. I guess it's back to beta 4.

Comment: Confirmed the same bug on beta5, as a workaround, you can uncheck the framework from the target membership section in the Xcode utilities panel.  For me, it works.  But it's definitely a Xcode bug.

Comment: This is fixed for me with Xcode 10 beta 6

Answer (score 1):

Xcode 10 beta 6 fixes this issue