# Crashlytics doesn't work with Xcode 10 beta

Tags: swift, cocoapods, crashlytics

I use Firestore and some of sub-services Google offers. Crashlytics is one of them. I recently started to use Xcode 10 beta and I've started to receive this error:

```
/Users/<user>/<some folders>/Pods/Fabric/iOS/Fabric.framework/Fabric(FABCompoundOperation.o)
ld: 154 duplicate symbols for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

And Build Phase stuff:

[image]

Here is Embed Pods Frameworks:

[image]

[image]

[image]

How to fix this?

P.S. I already cleaned and tried to build the project without any success.

Comment: Can you show "embed pods frameworks" section in build phases?

Comment: Sure. I will update my question immediately.

Comment: This is a known issue with Xcode 10 beta 5 and some binary frameworks - more at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602785/xcode-10b5-duplicate-symbol-linker-error-cant-compile-with-crashlytics