# How to get to older Xcode beta version?

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode10

I have deleted Xcode 10 beta 3 and upgraded to Xcode 10 beta 5.

However, due to [this bug](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51602785/xcode-10b5-duplicate-symbol-linker-error-cant-compile-with-crashlytics), I need to go back to an older beta (either 3 or 4).

There is no direct link to older betas at https://developer.apple.com/download/.

Is there a way to get to older betas of Xcode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can go to the https://developer.apple.com/download/ then simply copy the link under the download button of beta 5 and overwrite the 5 to 4 in the link.

So you can download all old versions you want.

Comment: Nice.. seems that the https://xcodereleases.com/ link to beta 4 points to the same resource..

Answer (score 0):

[Download from here](https://developer.apple.com/download/more/)

Don't download from any unofficial website

Comment: There are links to xcode command line tools + others xcode related stuff, but I am not able to find there a link to the Xcode beta itself there

Answer (score -1):

There is an unofficial website tracking Xcode releases here:

https://xcodereleases.com/