# Why Xcode 10 stop updating forward when 2 min remaining in completed?

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode, app-store, updates

I am updating Xcode 10 from Appstore but it stop updating when it 2 minute remaining in completed and freeze. so , please any suggestion for it.

Thank you.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because if your Xcode is not able update, then you need to ask it to Apple support. They can give proper reason behind that, it dont have any relation with programming.

Answer (score 1):

Prerequisite for the Xcode 10.0 update to taken place from your Xcode 9.x version is:

1) Minimum Mac OS required version: **10.13.6 (macOS High Sierra) or later**

2) A good network speed to finish the update

If you met all prerequisites then Be patience, it will take some more time because the estimated time is wrong sometimes.

What you should do in place of direct update from AppStore is:

Better not to update directly from the AppStore and get the DMG file from here.

[How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Though the size of DMG is larger, it has it's own benefits of getting the DMG over the direct update.

1) Whenever the new Xcode Version gets released, Many of the developer around the globe tries to update Xcode and thus overwhelm the Apple servers with requests which leads to slower the update speed and sometimes shows wrong estimated time. Now, if you go for DMG you get the better idea about the downloaded GBs out of total and get the exact estimates.

2) In direct update from AppStore, you cannot work on your project, while you are updating the Xcode and thus have to wait for hours to resume your work again. Which is not the case in DMG download.