# Updating Xcode cause fail in loading frameworks

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, updates, vuforia

I have updated my Xcode Client to 10.0 and installed all components. Now i have 9 errors in my project (a Swift project, that needs to be converted to Swift 4.2).
I use Facebook and Vuforia framework, and it seems like the problem lies there. I have tried to update the Pods, but this make no difference.
It is like the frameworks cant be read properly, because they are not converted yet. But i cant convert to Swift 4.2 as long as the build faild. Do i need to update the frameworks somehow?

Comment: updating framework is not any easy job , and may be cleared if you played with pod again (remove,re-add) , so it's best to stay with your xcode 9 until frameworks update to swift 4.2

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I will downgrade to xcode 9 and wait

Comment: select version and download https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file