# Could not locate device support files in Xcode

Tags: ios, iphone, xcode

I got following error in Xcode when run my app in my Device. Xcode Version is 10.01, My Device iOS Version 12.2 (iPhone 5S).

> Could not locate device support files.

[image]

Comment: There is no **Xcode 10.01**: can you please specify the version correctly?

Comment: Let me just clarify on why I voted to close this question as duplicate: almost every single release of Xcode comes with a new highest supported version of iOS, so the issue happened in the past and will happen in the future for almost any situation where you simply need to update Xcode (or download the device support files). And that's true for unreleased and upcoming versions of iOS like iOS 13.0, iOS 14.0, iOS 15.0, etc.

Answer (score 85, accepted):

You need to update your Xcode to the latest version. You can use this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file).

OR

You can download latest iOS device support file from [this github repository](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport) and copy the folder to this path of your current Xcode:

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

Now after restarting your Xcode, it should work fine.

---

You can get the latest device support files here:

- [iOS 13.6](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/13.6(FromXcode_12_beta_2_xip).zip)
- [iOS 14.0 (From Xcode 12 beta 4)](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/blob/master/DeviceSupport/14.0(FromXcode_12_beta_4_xip).zip)

Comment: I added iOS 13.2 support and now xcode crashes when runing on device

Comment: i deleted the related folders and device support but it still happens? what can I do?

Comment: s this something new? I don't remember having to download anything from GitHub before.

Comment: to be more concrete, you need to copy the folder, not files.

Comment: Please send the link for iOS 13.3?

Comment: @Vikas check here https://github.com/filsv/iPhoneOSDeviceSupport

Comment: can anyone commit the 12.4.5 (16G161) support files?

Comment: IMPORTANT: I updated the support files and Xcode kept crashing...eventually, had to update Xcode to resolve the issue. imho, thats probably the safest thing to do.

Comment: Somebody give this guy a medal for updating the answer to link to most recent files.

Comment: If your version is not there, have a look in the [pull requests](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/pulls), maybe someone already added it there.

Answer (score 5):

for iOS 12.2 you need `Xcode 10.2 beta 2` and if you don't want to download new xcode then you need to manually download device support files.

You can download 12.2 simulator from here and paste this folder at this path.

**Donload simulator :**  [Simulators](https://github.com/iGhibli/iOS-DeviceSupport/tree/master/DeviceSupport)

**Simulator Path :**

> /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/DeviceSupport/

After doing this you will able to run in your 12.2 device.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should update your Xcode to latest version to support running it on your iOS Device.

From overView [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_1_release_notes), it supports upto iOS 12.1:

> Xcode 10.1 includes SDKs for iOS 12.1, watchOS 5.1, macOS 10.14.1, and tvOS 12.1. Xcode 10.1 supports on-device debugging for iOS 8 and later, tvOS 9 and later, and watchOS 2 and later. Xcode 10.1 requires a Mac running macOS 10.13.6 or later.

You can read release not [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_10_2_beta_2_release_notes) and can download Xcode 10.2 beta version [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I am using Xcode's Latest Version (10.1)

Comment: You should update it to Xcode 10.2 beta 2 which includes SDKs for iOS 12.2 and then you can be able to run it on your iOS device. Checkout the links in my edits.