# How do You Fix an 'SDK version issue'?

Tags: ios, xcode, validation

I am trying to make my first application to submit to the App Store using Xcode, but when I was going through validation, it said that I had the wrong SDK version. How can I fix this?

- I tried archiving my app 19 more times, but it didn't work.
- I tried looking all over the web, but it didn't help.
- I also tried updating
  the Xcode app, but it said that it was temporarily unavailable.

When I would try to validate it sent me an error message saying that I had the wrong SDK version.

I thought that I did everything correct, but when I was at the last bit of validating it, it said:

### "SDK Version Issue. This app was built with the iOS 11.4 SDK. All iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 11 SDK or later, included in Xcode 9 or later. Further, starting March 2019, all iOS apps submitted to the App Store must be built with the iOS 12.1 SDK or later, included in Xcode 10.1 or later.

[Click here to see the image of the error message.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/j7sTu.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Can you please let us know the Xcode version that you are using? It is probably lower then Xcode version 10.1, if this is the case please update your Xcode and try to upload build again.

Comment: I tried updating my app but it said that the service was temporarily unavailable. :(

Comment: Try to download Xcode from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/5084797

Comment: Ok I will try it.

Comment: Will it delete the things I already put on the previous Xcode version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what I need to do is just put my app in a certain file and update my Xcode, and validate it again because on the error message it said that I had the wrong version of Xcode. When I said that I got another error message on the App Store

Thanks to everyone who helped me in the comments above - @manishsharma93 -. :D :)