# Xcode can’t be installed on “macOS Sierra” because macOS version 10.14.3 or later is required

Tags: xcode, xamarin, virtual-machine, macos-high-sierra

I need to pair my PC to a macOS to run the ios simulator in Xamarin .
After downloading and running macOS high Sierra 10.12 virtual machine and downloading the Xcode I got some error ,

The error : Xcode can’t be installed on "macOS Sierra" because macOS version 10.14.3 or later is required.

I don't know if I have to download a new virtual machine or to update macOS Sierra or to download an earlier version of Xcode but each of these takes too much time so I need a guaranteed link for downloading if this the solution .

Comment: You need macOS "Mojave" (10.14.+) if you want to develop for the latest iOS version|firmware.

Comment: you can download recent supported xCode version. Please refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file to download xcode

Comment: So you are running a virutal machine in your Apple Hardware, right? Since i wont assuming any illegal use or EULA violation here. What's the MacOs version of your host? if its mojave you dont need a VM. Otherwise update your host or your VM to Mojave to use the latest xcode. If you are using something that violate Apple's EULA i dont think you can find help here.

Answer (score 1):

From iOS 12.2 you'll need to have Xcode 10.2 to build.
Xcode 10.2 require Mac OS Mojave. So you'll need to update your os

Answer (score 0):

please visit https://xcodereleases.com/, & download xcode based on your requirements