# Xcode 11 GM Seed Invalid toolchain

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, xcode11

All of a sudden I started getting error today with Xcode 11 GM Seed when I upload the binary. What to do?

[image]

Comment: "...version of Xcode 9 and the SDK for iOS 11..." Something about that looks very wrong.

Comment: Not just you, I have the same issue. I don't think Apple released the correct version of the XCode 11 GM

Comment: Yeah something is going on, I uploaded a build just fine yesterday but I am also getting this error right now.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looks like [there is a new Xcode 11 GM seed 2](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/1292099) out that fixes this error.

Answer (score 0):

I just had the same problem after updating to version 11.2. After fighting for a couple of hours it is an error of that version. I have downloaded version 11.2.1 GM seed (8GB), decompress and replace the application. It has been torture, but I finally compiled it without problems.

https://developer.apple.com/download/

[https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_1_gm_seed_release_notes/](http://%20https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xcode_release_notes/xcode_11_2_1_gm_seed_release_notes/)

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Xcode version. If it is 11.2 then update to last 11.2.1 or onwards. Which seems working on these new versions.