# Xcode 11 release date

Tags: xcode, xcode11

I saw that Xcode 11 was released on September 16th in the App Store. When I check on my Mac and MacBook Pro I only see the previous version. was Xcode 11 pushed back? I am trying to run my device as a simulator but Xcode is telling me that it can not work with the device.

Comment: Can’t upload photos to comment but if you just google Xcode 11 release date it shows

Comment: No it doesn't. It shows the GM seed 2 as I said in my answer.

Comment: Please follow Xcode releases here:
[Xcode releases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

XCode 11 Public release is out now. You can get it from App store now.

Answer (score 0):

What was released on September 16th was the Golden Master. There have been two GM seeds so far.

**UPDATE** Xcode 11 did later go final on September 20.