# Can't download application in iOS 13.1.2

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, version

i made a app using xcode 10 and my app targate set is 12.0. I am unable to download app in iOS 13 and above version. i am able to download app iOS 12.4. So what is the issue. How to fix this.

Comment: How are you downloading it?  Are you trying to install it directly from Xcode?  You will need Xcode 11 for iOS 13 devices.

Comment: using diawi link

Comment: Also trying with Xcode 11 but facing same issue.

Comment: have you checked the diawi support page? https://www.diawi.com/knowledge-base/iOS/Cant-install-an-app-on-a-device-things-to-check

Comment: After downloading finish when tab on app icon to open it. Its show a popup Unable to download  XXXX app.

Answer (score 0):

Because you don't have latest disk image.

1. Go to Xcode. Check the disk image.
2. Add in your Xcode to disk image based on device current version.
3. Quit Xcode and reopen and check.
4. If you don't have disk image, visit below.

Visit [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)