# Xcode 11.4 beta error "Invalid toolchain"

Tags: ios, xcode, validation, flutter

When i first download Xcode with version of 11.4 beta, I can run app on simulator and devices from flutter project. However, I had a problem when I validate and upload my app:

> App Store Connect Operation Error
>
> Invalid Toolchain. Your app was built with an unsupported SDK or version of Xcode. If you plan to submit this build to the App Store, make sure you are using the versions listed in https://help.apple.com/xcode/mac/current/#/devf16aefe3b or later.

[image]

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 2):

Apple does not allow builds made using beta versions to submit to the app store. You would need to use the latest stable build, a list which is kept here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10335943/7498328

Comment: The enforcement for new apps vs. new builds (of existing apps) seems to vary if the beta is post-RC. I'm using Version 15.2 beta (15C5500c) -> (the RC according to wikipedia is 15C500b). I can upload a new build of an existing app (TF+published), but loading a new app resulted in this error.