# How do I Install the previous Xcode Version before 13.0

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I am making apps on Xcode, after updating it to 13.0 it completely ruined my interface and has no response. How can I download the previous version before 13.0?

Thank you.

Comment: Installing an older Xcode version will work for now, but ultimately you’re going to have to fix your project(s).

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/q/10335747/2227743

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Goto https://developer.apple.com (make sure you sign in, you'll have to at some point)
- Goto "Develop" (top of the screen)
- Goto "Downloads"

[image: Developer/Downloads]

- Goto "More" (just below the top menu bar)
- Type in "Xcode" in the search field

[image: Search it]

- Scroll down to the version you want

[image: Is this what you're looking for]

- Click "View Details"
- Download and install, probably grab a cuppa ... and a meal ... and catch up on some reading or viewing, it will take a while :/