# Flutter: Not able to run the program after setting up Android Studio on MacOs Big Sur (VirtualBox)

Tags: xcode, macos, flutter, android-studio

Recently started Flutter coding on Mac VirtualBox.

I completed the setup of Android Studio (Arctic Fox latest), Flutter (Latest), and Xcode 13.

Base OS - Windows 10 --> VirtualBox OS - MacOS Big Sur.

I have also set up pod by using `pod init` and `pod install`. Changed iOS Deployment target 9.0.

I have also tried restarting the system as the error states but it doesn't work.

I am getting the following error while running the default program.

```
Launching lib/main.dart on iPhone X in debug mode...
Running Xcode build...
Xcode build done.                                           133.6s
Failed to build iOS app
Error output from Xcode build:
↳
    --- xcodebuild: WARNING: Using the first of multiple matching destinations:
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:dvtdevice-DVTiOSDeviceSimulatorPlaceholder-iphonesimulator:placeholder, name:Any iOS Simulator Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D2B9E0F0-9684-4430-9756-20B2DCA59DED, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 5s }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B708551C-FEAF-4FCA-A44B-BA81BB89CFA0, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 5s }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:45DCA8E3-C7DB-4648-ADC2-F4F25E857BD6, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 6 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EEC17F43-F5E6-4564-98D9-1BFCD878000F, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 6 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7A9CF32B-0E67-4131-8960-E57749F35F0C, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F63948F8-A43A-44B2-8134-621F1972EA25, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 6 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:217096B7-1521-4752-A669-C453C471C7B8, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 6s }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E53D2609-664D-4F74-AB52-E01291B20943, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 6s }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FC7CBB90-A142-47B0-AFF0-01899C8A39FE, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1D1AF5EF-D647-409E-B6A5-233D20C92FF3, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 6s Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E8B8179D-6A5D-4631-AE5F-29F0D9F63209, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 7 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3B6282F4-DF48-4D12-9C37-9CF9A4EB4A9E, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 7 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:01F8B69B-436D-4851-88AF-D31F1EC85D95, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:46804ABC-9BC8-418A-BD55-04704F42950C, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 7 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E3B587F-0B7B-4E45-8496-B10932413CC1, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A203FFA2-0544-43A9-BEB3-E0574C5823DD, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:79EB131D-7BEE-492A-B844-F3E1F4119D6F, OS:13.5, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:185311D2-5435-462F-9D2E-BE839E420460, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C0BF67A1-533A-4281-9967-1F1CEDD797F9, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:11BA6FC5-8A85-4767-AB60-397A5C1BFEA4, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DCF8D0EE-A740-4882-87B0-7CBBA9000426, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F596662A-89EF-4888-AEAD-9CC6C9C39EF1, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:03709F8C-2DDD-4EEA-A131-1EAC1A674322, OS:11.4, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:62FB0ABE-8E7D-4C46-AAB1-5B944828CF32, OS:12.4, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B6A6BFAD-E224-4DE2-982A-885816489C9B, OS:13.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:41D07E16-D02B-4F80-AF73-701B500E8603, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B4936802-0CB5-4FAC-8D0C-2ECBD529DB37, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4A659EBE-859A-407B-B8FC-8E92D87056AC, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EF9BE8ED-B9A5-4504-8265-E593AF41D387, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:40FE30D7-A403-4C56-9B06-96A6D9582CAD, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 8 Plus }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4C3AE4BD-A868-4DA5-BADF-2AD02972D359, OS:13.5, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A45E5BCC-8ED6-4D6F-9490-016D83DFB053, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5BB2CC2A-7D38-4746-A99E-17BE13E9BAED, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:67FBF71E-F7AF-485D-8AB3-D24404A7698E, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:094AAB66-317C-4FA8-9C5B-D48CECBB5D90, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CCF721D3-7896-4AC1-A3F5-8FA72FD90AE2, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DDE13EBB-3084-4C69-94BC-68BDFD8745C1, OS:13.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:976EBE14-5D78-43C1-83EB-0460965949F9, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:EF5156FD-734D-4A7E-86EB-FBFB67F1A89F, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4F58E8ED-2FA8-4BD0-AD7F-5E3126C58A30, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FE129827-375E-4549-8D98-9969BC0733D0, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:77B12D27-EFA2-4024-A412-C3E6FC56F22B, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2EAA6A94-283B-43D6-971E-AB25BB3D7CF3, OS:13.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D8A3A3EE-5DDA-47CF-92D3-6E7CB6CC1531, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:38E75408-0D40-4AB4-AC9F-13AC073E7FDB, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B122D7BF-A2EE-4BC2-B4F9-DC13189ACEE4, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0BA2A626-A321-4ED7-941E-F6DB8D0EDC75, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B0648BD7-40C7-4A80-BDA3-870758F37E99, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 11 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0B4EAB4D-7037-4CC0-BA62-AE7B32A753F2, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C18B8E6-EE18-4359-A232-25BC634A9E6B, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:66CF2A39-6192-4412-BE08-E6F2F8E667C1, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:90B8B802-B6F6-4967-9C9D-1564DD7A9D97, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:D2BA7913-E76D-4590-841F-27620010D8EE, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CA31A23F-C924-4DA4-AAD9-CB6C4D378975, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4FD1D9C2-2421-4175-AEE7-1DED64AF5EB1, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0A32005B-78B0-4B1A-988F-43EC6A5EA15A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1C86403F-ED93-4611-8123-00C142E93B68, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:B1404653-697C-4ABD-ACFA-98AED84C69C5, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:12B78839-86B4-4A43-BE26-10BA8D192E34, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:044A4E8C-CC29-46FD-9353-E1AC346C6D44, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:270332D9-447D-4C3C-B68E-CE59E62FE404, OS:14.3, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:9949BE80-6006-403C-A5DA-83C40F3AF3F3, OS:14.4, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4D014C8C-FE5F-4320-97EC-E6042FA54E40, OS:14.5, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A68F6381-8CF7-4AA1-BCE8-495EC6A2C86D, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 12 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7E0DCDA2-6187-4486-AA6E-35D3CD5C3D2A, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CB52D278-1B6F-4570-A416-39A42BD6E010, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5E9E8A50-6186-4592-BF52-3EFCC87D779F, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 Pro Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F97C4D7C-8187-4FB8-88C3-FF7DD1C4FC54, OS:15.0, name:iPhone 13 mini }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:32287658-989B-401B-963C-1ACDB0876919, OS:11.4, name:iPhone SE (1st generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:086A9A21-9F39-453C-812B-1831598DF86F, OS:12.4, name:iPhone SE (1st generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4E942EF9-A174-4B39-B11A-61288C8C0B06, OS:13.5, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:529C1765-99AE-4C7A-B2A9-B37C1C5FCA9C, OS:14.0.1, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:C4D32105-1493-44A8-BE27-84EED16E4AEC, OS:14.3, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A026A754-0AB6-4F62-9403-3240C039B9B4, OS:14.4, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:CAF9B669-CE69-4021-937D-39CDDC48A56A, OS:14.5, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8E58C421-320E-41C4-906C-A08D4DD39146, OS:15.0, name:iPhone SE (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4CA9F645-9751-48FC-A189-63EA923454D4, OS:11.4, name:iPhone X }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3B0AA901-740B-414D-BEC2-4BB30A690E97, OS:12.4, name:iPhone X }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:06AAB4D1-53C0-4229-A8BE-7318BFCCD41A, OS:12.4, name:iPhone Xs }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3C7C9DF9-BD77-4C44-B100-3D339E2BB3DD, OS:12.4, name:iPhone Xs Max }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F460F95E-A66F-4C07-9E26-6C77FBA262F8, OS:12.4, name:iPhone Xʀ }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:591D7315-E774-4202-96B4-3249856EAA98, OS:14.0.1, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DD2ACA3F-8111-4EDE-8524-251543021F73, OS:14.3, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5938F5B3-62C6-4FF3-B356-8F06D9386B1B, OS:14.4, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1EAF7B99-1B6D-454B-9AC1-138C3742AC21, OS:14.5, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A7EFAA71-F428-4FF9-AE52-AE65F48D0A3A, OS:15.0, name:iPod touch (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS, id:dvtdevice-DVTiPhonePlaceholder-iphoneos:placeholder, name:Any iOS Device }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:510CD427-372C-4B8F-9A35-73AE72A1B122, OS:11.4, name:iPad (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:46A3C8A2-EDE1-475D-A0BA-85DB44DB60FD, OS:12.4, name:iPad (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8337E732-2647-4D75-B87C-F69B4AD539E4, OS:11.4, name:iPad (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A78F426F-6762-458A-8181-956A8BD2B37C, OS:12.4, name:iPad (6th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6D52BC9E-E399-4E25-929F-843A0BB0AE1A, OS:13.5, name:iPad (7th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:3CE0DBFB-79CB-4A78-A4A3-0D6ADCD695AD, OS:14.0.1, name:iPad (8th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:458360E0-B7BD-45AE-9583-8C112257C047, OS:14.3, name:iPad (8th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DAA24E50-E3C2-437C-B14E-DCF592EB919E, OS:14.4, name:iPad (8th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4438B6BE-229E-4A0D-9A6E-1E78FA81A816, OS:14.5, name:iPad (8th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4693AE52-A569-46C4-919D-25826635DD9A, OS:15.0, name:iPad (9th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:320AEF10-7ADD-4020-86DB-2309A06EE3C8, OS:11.4, name:iPad Air }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BFC2CCD1-F4F2-4EA6-955C-CA509381FF4E, OS:12.4, name:iPad Air }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A571A6E6-24AD-47BC-8D6C-FF73A287F64A, OS:12.4, name:iPad Air (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E46FAC5F-CD27-4682-B704-64D675F40D9A, OS:13.5, name:iPad Air (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F0190012-B656-4D2E-9914-27E6682E5751, OS:14.0.1, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:41A61A17-FCBD-4C78-89D4-DB04CA6EAFBD, OS:14.3, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:F89233C0-1323-4018-906A-E5D5DCBEE655, OS:14.4, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:40BEA923-702C-4162-8FA5-D5CA4D42F1EA, OS:14.5, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:09DE7FF3-FCCD-45B5-BB71-A4B40550991E, OS:15.0, name:iPad Air (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:98F4133C-E406-48E0-841B-DF4E153AFE0D, OS:11.4, name:iPad Air 2 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:4F036E1D-3EFD-435B-A08F-C690B7F4520E, OS:12.4, name:iPad Air 2 }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0655ED78-B242-413F-984C-F2CD67B56CA8, OS:11.4, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:99C573B6-A2D3-492A-A052-573C0419E6B9, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6341BF4F-AA4A-4C58-9070-969AF31B030E, OS:13.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:52FABD11-2B32-43EF-9FAC-1CEB7EDCC677, OS:14.0.1, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:06B1395D-39D9-490A-A350-2A6EABBA33EF, OS:14.3, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7FDDEF02-5188-4EB1-9113-312CD9A4CC57, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2562A8A0-39C2-44F5-B45C-2CEC71982B60, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:1A51897D-936D-48EA-BA42-338006C674F9, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (9.7-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6735AEE3-DAD7-4636-AB31-94390335C3BD, OS:11.4, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:064ED7DE-7D49-4AEE-824F-A126A50C03AA, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (10.5-inch) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:DD765C61-D452-4879-A0C4-B3A87A3DE45A, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (1st generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7A8E5BF4-FEB8-4E9A-8C8B-F0403BA1E4BE, OS:13.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:40165D3E-27B4-4CD6-945C-3DB4191829F3, OS:14.0.1, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:24ABB893-8B17-4BAE-98C6-78C6C71936A2, OS:14.3, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:90B54D81-2637-4C0B-9A49-33B656FBC781, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:0908EC5D-DCAC-4137-8B56-C71CB195DE77, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:FCDD3816-378E-4677-89B3-0862E2D8FC6F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (11-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:E5D09F62-6E6E-4AFC-ACFA-4CAD64E65EA3, OS:11.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:BF2B84A2-9EF8-40BE-BE21-A5DE36FA55CD, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (1st generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:43711B7D-50C5-45B1-9E42-6DA4057E884F, OS:11.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:2844CE0C-086C-444A-9D5D-13DEEBDA05D2, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (2nd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:62A01F15-93E9-4491-B6EB-6E09C1CA4C5B, OS:12.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (3rd generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:47ABF0E9-E82C-48F2-B607-9D1DBD93C88B, OS:13.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7E3C9217-9205-48CC-AC73-01F4F4D5FAD8, OS:14.0.1, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:5C61AA01-1852-478C-9085-4385FEF38E1D, OS:14.3, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:7CF422B3-B01B-469D-8CE1-F4470D41B695, OS:14.4, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (4th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:8AE5CE36-E3A1-4770-8CD6-0B7E9FF84C11, OS:14.5, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:6A646008-CF0F-4C28-A590-31823A11B46F, OS:15.0, name:iPad Pro (12.9-inch) (5th generation) }
    { platform:iOS Simulator, id:A7A2F4AF-C0ED-4AF5-857E-2149D3709BAA, OS:15.0, name:iPad mini (6th generation) }
    ** BUILD FAILED **


Xcode's output:
↳
    2021-10-17 20:40:16.981 ibtoold[2034:36928] DEBUG: Added to environment: {
        TMPDIR = "/var/folders/86/yrrf7k_j0c3bb581j17g_zmm0000gn/T/E1FE35AA-EBAF-4898-A5F0-D0052C0F100F";
    }
    /* com.apple.actool.errors */
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/ios/Runner/Assets.xcassets: error: Failed to launch AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent via CoreSimulator spawn
        Underlying Errors:
            Description: Failed to handshake with platform tool
            Failure Reason: Failed to open connection over FIFOs with platform tool
            Underlying Errors:
                Description:
                Recovery Suggestion: Try restarting your computer
                Underlying Errors:
                    Description: Failed to open FIFOs for handshaking with platform tool
                    Failure Reason: AssetCatalogSimulatorAgent exited before we could handshake
    /* com.apple.actool.compilation-results */
    /Users/vinayhp/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-dyrrggdwohefevbubqgedlsbaufy/Build/Intermediates.noindex/Runner.build/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.build/assetcatalog_generated_info.plist
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20@3x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon20x20~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29@3x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon29x29~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40@3x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon40x40~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@2x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon60x60@3x.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76@2x~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon76x76~ipad.png
    /Users/vinayhp/StudioProjects/demo/build/ios/Debug-iphonesimulator/Runner.app/AppIcon83.5x83.5@2x~ipad.png

    note: Using new build system
    note: Planning
    note: Build preparation complete
    note: Building targets in parallel

Could not build the application for the simulator.
Error launching application on iPhone X
```

Comment: You have the connection error with FIFOs. Try to look that.

Comment: @RakeshSaini I am new to MAC.. not able to follow that error.. Please help.. I think FIFO means 'First In First Out' Right? But how to rectify that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved:

I uninstalled Xcode 13 which was installed from App Store and reinstalled Xcode 13 xip downloaded externally.

Reference: [How to download Xcode DMG or XIP file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file)

How to install?

1. Copy the Xcode.xip file into Applications folder and double click on it.
2. It will extract xCode.app
3. After extraction delete Xcode.xip
4. Run in terminal: sudo xcode-select --switch /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
5. Xcode should run normally now. Open your project, Changed iOS Deployment target to 9.0.
6. Open Android Studio, Select your emulator. (I choose iPhone X - iOS 11.4)
7. Run my app. (I worked well without any error.)