# Trying to upload my bundle in AppStore Connect for TestFlight App + flutter + XCode + iOS

Tags: ios, flutter, dart, mobile, testflight

[image]

im trying to upload my bundle for Testflight app in App store Connect and im getting the above error.

Is there any solution or a way to resolve this.

Comment: what version of xcode you have and thus you're cocoapods is latest version?

Comment: im using xcode 14.0.1

Comment: Update Xcode version to 14.1 or later without that not possible.

Comment: there was no update for my xcode in my app store in mac
is there any other way to update the version

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file