Command `pod install` failed. --> Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: Please upgrade XCode
I installed Xcode 14.3.1 from the Apple Developer Website, and now I am trying to create an expo app that uses SDK 52 and react-native-pytorch-core
When running npm run ios, I get the following error:
✔ Finished prebuild
⚠️  Something went wrong running `pod install` in the `ios` directory.
Command `pod install` failed.
└─ Cause: Invalid `Podfile` file: Please upgrade XCode.

 #  from /Users/arushgarg/Downloads/mobile-ml/MobileML/ios/Podfile:39
 #  -------------------------------------------
 #  
 >    use_react_native!(
 #      :path => config[:reactNativePath],
 #  -------------------------------------------

pod install --repo-update --ansi exited with non-zero code: 1

Xcode 14.3.1 is compatible upto iOS 16.4, while Expo52 needs iOS 15.1 and above. The Podfile says platform :ios, podfile_properties['ios.deploymentTarget'] || '15.1'

sorry, is there an issue with downloading Xcode 16.1 (the latest one) from here and trying one more time? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10335747/how-to-download-xcode-dmg-or-xip-file
